# Help identifying wedge tile piece

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[image]

2 x 3 flat tile piece. Same size as 2 x 3 wedge plate but I cannot find anything listed with the smooth top. "P 9" marking on the back with "lego" stamp but no part id number.

Answer (score 10):

What I thought was a lego mark is actually 0C31. This must be a megablok. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to Bricks SE. Perfectly valid question and answer, no need to apologize.

Comment: 0C31 looks remarkably like LEGO, when turned upside down, so I can't fault you for this mistake. Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Comment: It'd be nice to edit the original question to include this info.  It seems weird that it still stays there was a LEGO stamp on it.